# Split string and add binary variables in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a pd data set with several columns. One of the columns represents the affiliation for the researcher, that can have one or multiple names separated by a comma.

I need to split it and create binary variables for each individual value (Affiliated institutions). Attached an image of an example of the original table and what I need to get as an output

**Example of the input and output**

[image]

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Try `pd.concat([df['ID'], df.Affiliation.str.split(", ", expand=True).stack().str.get_dummies().groupby(level=0).sum()],1)`; where `df` is your starting dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your task by using this snippet of code:

```
initial_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2],
                           'Affiliation': ['University 1, University 2, University 3', 'University 3, University 4']}) # here should be your initial DataFrame
processed_df = (pd.get_dummies(initial_df.Affilation.apply(lambda x: x.split(', '))
                                                    .apply(pd.Series)
                                                    .stack()).sum(level=0)
                                                             .assign(ID=initial_df['ID']))
```